# How to remove HTML tags in CSV file- PHP

Tags: php, html, csv

I am trying to download CSV file from php values. But the output file is included with all the html tags.
I have used the following part of code for CSV file.

```
     header('Content-Type: application/x-csv');
     header('Content-disposition:attachment;filename=file.csv');
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
 <tr><td> 2017-11-05 10:38:05 </td> <td>  3 </a> </td> <td>  Full Speed </a> 
 </td><td>56</td><td> <div id= "level2" > Level 2 </div> </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>2017-11-05 10:37:03 </td> <td>
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
 2017-11-05 10:38:05, 3 , Full , Level 2 , 2017-11-05 10:37:03.
```

NOTE: data is extracted from array variables in php (not from sql/database)

Comment: strip_tags? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: @Ofir Baruch: Do I need to add all the php variables as 'allowable tags'?

Comment: Why isn't `speed` part of the expected output?

Comment: @Ofir Baruch :- Please upvote my question if you ha e downvoted. I ha e accepted the following answer. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags)() on the string you want to filter.

If you dont want to strip all tags, you can use the second parameter of strip_tags*

```
$str = ' <tr><td> 2017-11-05 10:38:05 </td> <td>  3 </a> </td> <td>  Full Speed </a> 
 </td><td>56</td><td> <div id= "level2" > Level 2 </div> </td></tr> 
 <tr><td>2017-11-05 10:37:03 </td> <td> ';
$str = strip_tags($str); // Your data without html tags
```

If you want to have it in a single line, you can go further and do a [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)() on it:

```
$str = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $str);
```

---

*Lets say, you dont want to remove paragraphs or links, you would call strip_tags() like that:

```
$str = strip_tags($str, '<p><a>');
```

Comment: How can use the string (in your code: $str) dynamically from the output file?

Comment: You have to select your data into $str. I dont how you get them, so its up to you. If you i.e. use `file_get_contents('your.csv');` then you would have to go for `$str = file_get_contents('your.csv');`